# SSL cert on ELB or EC2?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have some questions on setting up SSL certs on AWS setup (ELB + EC2)..

1. Where do I put the SSL cert, on the ELB or EC2 or both?
2. Depending on the answer to question #1, how do I configure the port forwarding on the ELB, do I do it this way? HTTP Port 80 -> HTTP Port 80 and HTTPS Port 443 -> HTTPS Port 443

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ELB in one of two ways:

**SSL un-encrytpion at the ELB**

In this mode, you'll give the ELB the cert and key. It will un-encrypt the request and pass it to your servers unencrypted. The benefit of this is that you can reduce the CPU load of your servers.

**The ELB just acts as a passthrough.**

The ELB can act as a dumb passthrough. It won't need the cert or key. In order to set it up this way, instead of using the HTTPS option, set it as TCP port.

[image: See Image]